# Statistical test suggestion

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

I need to find an appropriate statistical test (likelihood ratio test, t-test, etc.) on the following: Let $\{X_i;Y_i\}^n_{i=1}$ be an i.i.d. sample of a random vector $(X;Y)$ and assume that $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 
  Y\\
  X
\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$~$N$ $\left[\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 
  \mu_1\\
  \mu_2
\end{smallmatrix} \bigr),
\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 
  1 & .5\\
  .5 & 1 
\end{smallmatrix} \bigr) \right]$. The hypotheses are:
$H_0=\mu_1+\mu_2\le 1$; 
$H_1=\mu_1+\mu_2\gt 1$

By looking at this information, how do I know which test is the most appropriate? Is it because the data is i.i.d. I can simply take a likelihood ratio test? A good explanation on what test is more appropriate than another one would be greatly appreciated. This would definitely clear my mind.

Comment: Have you noticed that $X+Y\sim N(\mu_1+\mu_2, 3)$ and $X-Y\sim N(\mu_1-\mu_2, 1)$ are uncorrelated and jointly normal, whence they are independent? Thus you can digest your dataset into $\{(X_i+Y_i)\}$, view it as a set of iid realizations of a Normal distribution with known variance and unknown mean, and ask how to compare its mean to zero. This is an elementary textbook problem with a well-known answer (a Z test).

Comment: @whuber thanks! I will look into this more carefully. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @whuber what I find difficult though is that I face a composite hypothesis testing and I don't know how to set this is up. any suggestion would be welcomed

Comment: @whuber also because I face a multivariate case that makes it more difficult no?

Comment: also I have to first use a likelihood ratio test ... that's where I am having difficulty for a likelihood ratio test under a composite system

Comment: My initial observation reduces your problem to a univariate one: $X-Y$ is irrelevant. The Z test *is* an LR test.

Comment: @whuber agree but firm I must do something similar to this: http://www.stat.sc.edu/~habing/courses/703/GLRTExample.pdf and derive with respect to $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$.

Comment: Are you saying that this is really a homework question and that you don't actually have any interest in the test itself?

Comment: @whuber it is a previous year practice exam question - so yes not the test itself

Comment: @whuber Shouldn't the $X-Y$ distribution have $\mu_1-\mu_2$ as its mean? I realize it doesn't matter for this problem, but it just worries me to see the typo sitting there.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks: good eyes.  I fixed it--and caught a typo on your part, too :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's investigate the distribution of $Z=X+Y$.

$E[X+Y] = \mu_1 + \mu_2$

and

$var(Z) = var(X+Y) = var(X) + var(Y) + 2Cov(X,Y)$ 
which equals to 3 in your case.

What remains is testing $H_0: Z < 1$ which can be done with the usual t-test.

Hope this helps.